# Yii2 Gridview Dropdown Button in Action column

Tags: gridview, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to make my action column button as dropdown button in my gridview, this is my code

```
// ... GridView configuration ...
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',               
            'template' => '{sell} {delete}',
            'buttons' => [
                'sell' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return Html::a('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></button>', $url, [
                                'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Sell Tickets'),
                                'data-toggle' => "modal",
                                'data-target' => "#myModal",
                                'data-method' => 'post',
                    ]);
                },
                'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return Html::a('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></button>', $url, [
                                'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Delete'),
                                'data-toggle' => "modal",
                                'data-target' => "#myModal",
                                'data-method' => 'post',
                    ]);
                },
            ],
            'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                if ($action == 'sell') {
                    $url = Url::toRoute(['trip/sell', 'id' => $model->tripScheduleId]);
                    return $url;
                } else {
                    $url = Url::toRoute(['trip/delete', 'id' => $model->tripScheduleId]);
                    return $url;
                }
            },
        ],
```

and this is the view

[image]

I've followed many in so or any source but nothing work on me.

Answer (score 1):

`buttons` is an array of rendering function, just render your dropdown there and remove the `urlCreator` section.

`urlCreator` is used to build URLs for the default buttons in the template so by rendering a dropdown with the right URLs you won't need it.

```
'template' => '{actions}',
'buttons' => [
    'actions' => function ($url, $model) {
        //return you dropdown here
    }
],
```

Just don't care about `$url` parameter and create your URLs inside the function.